# Becoming a user of a developer account if you are already an owner of another

Tags: android, google-play

I am a freelance game developer and I have my own Google Developer account.

I have a client who wishes me to help with publishing the app on their account. They currently sent me an invite on an alternate email address.

Can I accept the invite on my main google account and be owner of mine and user in theirs? How would it work, how do I select which of the accounts I want to access?

If that doesn't work and I need to make a separate account, it seems I cannot make a new google account using the alt email unless I give a phone number.

So, can I use the same phone no for both?

Comment: This isn't a programming related problem question.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen several other questions about the developer account using the same tags (even if not related to this one), so I figured it was ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using several developer accounts with the same google account. The devloper console will show a menu to select the developer account. This is found at the top right at the android icon.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. This makes sense. I'll mark it as correct as soon as it will let me.

I really wish they would put this info out somewhere.